# chol hamoed outings

Tags: halacha, travel, chol-hamoed

The Halocho rules that, on chol hamoed, one may only do melochos (creative labors) which are *needed* for the Yom Tov. What justifies doing melochos when going on family trips? Surely these trips can be done after Yom Tov!

Comment: Do you mean to ask about Yom Tov (as the question body says) or Chol Hamoed (as the title says)?  (This is also the answer to your question, I think)

Comment: chol hamoed, but the poskim speak about chol hamoed as tzorech hamoed.

Comment: Later near-duplicate: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/47316

Answer (score 5):

*Sh'miras Shabas K'hilchasah*, chapter 66, paragraph 58 and footnote 224, discusses riding in a car on a pleasure trip on *chol hamoed*, as follows. *Rav Sh'lomo Zalman* Auerbach suggests that it may be permissible even if one can walk, because the *m'lacha* involved in riding in a car is *hav'ara*, burning [gasoline], which is permitted on *chol hamoed*; but he's unsure, as operating the car may be considered *m'leches uman*, skilled labor, which would be forbidden. *Rav Moshe* Feinstein suggests that driving is more pleasurable than walking for most people, so that — *SSK* adds — as long as the trip is for some pleasure for *chol hamoed* (e.g. visiting a friend), it's permissible as *tzorech hamoed*, needed for the holiday.

Comment: I assume you mean the second edition of _SSK_? I don't see a chapter 66 in mine.

Comment: Second volume, yes, @DoubleAA.

Comment: I asked about _editions_ not _volumes_. (But you have indirectly confirmed my suspicion, as the first edition was published in only one volume.)

Comment: @DoubleAA, it's volume 2, but afaict the first edition thereof. (At least, there's no indication in it to the contrary.) And it looks like it was published separately from the first volume. Hence, not a second edition in any sense, but a second volume. (That's why I answered as I did above.)

Comment: (relevant especially to the comments) http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/74108

Comment: and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/57485/why-do-women-wear-ponytail-elastics-on-shabas/57493#comment153862_57493