# Why is driving on Chol Hamo'ed allowed?

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, chol-hamoed

Meleches Uman, skilled labor, is not permitted on Chol Hamo'ed even for the needs of the mo'ed (M.B. 540:1).

Common practice indicates that driving on Chol Hamo'ed is allowed.  However, driving is a melacha (burning) and it seems to be a skilled activity, as it takes practice to learn how to do it.  So why is it allowed on Chol Hamo'ed?

I have a theory as to why it is accepted as being permitted, but I am looking for a *source* that discusses and permits this explicitly.

Comment: The fact that it is a learned action does not make it skilled labor. Whether or not the average person can do it or only a skilled laborer who is involved in that work can do it is the criteria. See chol hamoed kihilchaso chapter 2 siff 141 and onward, but especially see note 280.

Comment: @user6591 Can the average person not write?  I don't have the sefer you are referring to, but I have heard my description of meleches uman explicitly made by some prominent Rabbonim.  And some things which the average person can _not_ do are permitted if they don't require learning.

Comment: Whether or not writing is maaseh uman is the machlokes in the begining of siman 545.

Comment: From the explanation of the opinion to say it is not maaseh uman given in the mishna berurah because people aren't makpid to write perfectly, we can assume any learned work which isn't done with a skilled laborers precision is not called maaseh uman. The other opinion believes all writing is done perfectly making us all skilled laborers as far as writing goes. But I don't think we all drive perfectly:)

Comment: Burning is not a prohibited melacha on Yom Tov. Starting a new fire is Nolad and there is no Nolad concerns on Chol Hamoed TTBOMK.

Comment: I do think that I've seen your question addressed though so I'm looking around. Maybe it was one of the poskim from Israel?

Comment: Near duplicate: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/37198

Comment: @DoubleAA "Burning is not a prohibited melacha on Yom Tov"? I've never heard that before. Do you have a source? (It's of course permitted _l'tzorech hayom_, though, which is relevant here.)

Comment: @user6591 I don't know what you see from that Mishna Berura - the point is that since people aren't makpid to write, it doesn't require skill to do - nothing to do with how prevalent a skill it is.  If anything, it shows my point as opposed to yours.  See the nosei keilim on the Tur, it's clear the discussion by writing has to do with how much of an "art" it is, not with how widespread the skill is.

Comment: @DoubleAA That is a machlokes Rishonim.  Ashkenazim hold that havara is assur shelo l'tzoreich klal on Yom Tov, because it is still a melacha, just has a hetter of mitoch.  Even Rashi, who holds shelo l'tzoreich klal is muttar, is because of mitoch, just that mitoch allows everything, but Rashi holds the fact that it is "in principle" assur has a nafka mina for being gozeir muktza.

Comment: @DoubleAA And the Rambam holds new fire is not Nolad, it's an application of efshar mib'od yom, which also means that it is a melacha, just normally permitted through ochel nefesh.

Comment: @YEZ Yes. For the purposes of this question though, we don't paskin like that Rambam and it is Letzorekh Klal.

Comment: @DoubleAA Chol Hamo'ed has an even lower level than letzorech klal - I am just pointing out that it is indeed a melacha, albeit with a hetter to it. Chol Hamo'ed has it's own gedarim for its hetterim, of which l'tzorech hamo'ed for a maaseh uman is not one.

Comment: @YEZ You're making the same point as msh210. I wasn't trying to be overly technical before. Something muttar on Yom Tov is certainly muttar on Chol Hamoed is the point I was making.

Comment: @YEZ it's dependant on how carefully one writes. If everyone is very careful to write in an exact way than that opinion will say that everyone is an uman in this feild. I only mentioned this to address your point about writing which is a good question as far as accepting that klal from the seffer I mentioned. His sources are many rishonim and achronim. I ended off my comment as showing that the sticking point between the two opinions about writing would not apply as everyone drives and noone is careful do it perfectly as would a nascar driver.

Comment: As far as the learned skill theory goes, the seffer i mentioned also brings from authorities that many learned skills are not called maaseh uman. One pointed to folding laundry. In fact the Ramban proved this point by using writing as a mashal for a learned skill that is not skilled labor. I guess we know what side of the fence he is on regarding that machlokes.

Answer (score 3):

The seffer Ashrei Ha'ish vol. 3 chapter 8 siff 44 quotes Reb Elyashev that driving a car is muttar on chol hamoed as it is not considered maaseh uman. No further explenation is given.