# Why do women wear ponytail elastics on Shabas?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, mikvah-ritual-bath, maseches-shabbos, hotzaa-carrying-reshuyot

So I was studying the start of *Bame Isha* in the *Bavli* ([*Shabas* 57](http://e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=236)), and it seems a woman can't wear a tight strap or string in her hair outside (of an *eruv*) on *Shabas* (lest she remove it out of doors because she's going to be *tovel*). Looking at [*Shulchan Aruch* (with *Mishna B'rura*) 303](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49625&st=&pgnum=179) seems only to confirm this (and apply it even to unmarried and elderly women). Yet it seems to me that very many a woman does wear a ponytail, [bound](//commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Hair_tie.jpg) by an [elastic](//commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Hair_ties.jpg), outside of an *eruv* on *Shabas*. What gives?

- Am I misapplying the *halacha* to ponytail elastics? That is, does it not apply to them? Why not?
- Or am I mistaken about the prevalence of ponytail-elastic use on *Shabas*, and, in fact, those careful about *halacha* don't wear them?
- Or is it simply that many women sin — viz, wear ponytail elastics even though it's forbidden?
- Or what?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shemirat Shabbat Kehilchata (16:18, cf. footnotes 69, 82) notes that the practice is to be lenient and cites the following from [*Orchot Chayim*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aaron_ben_Jacob_ha-Kohen) (Shabbat 261) to try and justify the practice, though in closing with a reference to the Beiur Halacha (303:18 sv. *Ki*) he indicates how weak he believes the justification is.

> וכן האשה לא תצא בדבר שהוא חוצץ בפני הטביל' וטעמא דמלתא דלמא מתרמיא לה טבילה של מצוה בשבת ושריא לה ואתיא לאתויינהו ד' אמות בר"הר ואע"פי שאין מטבילין את הכלים בשבת זהו מפני שמתקן כלי אבל הטמא מותר לטבול מפני שנראה כמיקר. ואיכא מאן דאמר ה"מ דאיכא למיחש בהכי במקומות שטובלו' בנהר אבל במקומות שטובלות במקואות שבתוך הבתים לית לן בה. וכתב הר' דוד בר לוי ז"ל ועכשיו פשט המנהג ברוב מקומותינו להיות הנשים יוצאות בכל אלו הדברים שקולעות בהן שערן אפי' בדברים שחוצצים בטבילה ואין מוחה בידן ג"כ בכל התכשיטין האחרים שיש לחוש דלמא שלפא ומחויא יוצאות בהדיא ויוצאות אף בדורות קדמוננו שהיו חסידים ואנשי מעשה ואין מי יערער בדבר ואפשר שהתנהגו בדברים אלו כשאר הדברים שאמרו עליהן הנח להם לישראל מוטב שיהיו שוגגין ואל יהיו מזידין וכן דעת ר"ת ז"ל...‏
>   ...and there are some who say that [this prohibition] is only in places where they [ritually] dip in rivers, but in places where they [ritually] dip in *Mikvaot* that are in houses, there is no need to be concerned... [my partial translation]

(See too ShA OC 303:18 that women wearing prohibited "adornments" on Shabbat is not a new phenomenon and various rabbinic responses to it. והמבין יבין)

Comment: Not seeing it in _SSK_ there (or anywhere in _SSK_, actually). (I'm atm checking a local synagogue's copy, "new, fixed, and expanded" in 5739.)

Comment: @msh210 My volume is rather yellowed so I assume it is not any of the redone versions but probably the original. It was printed in Jerusalem in 5725.