# Are you allowed to put your hair in a ponytail on Shabbos?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, hair

If someone has thin hair that easily comes out are they allowed to put their hair in a ponytail or remove the ponytail if the intention is not to take out any hair?

Comment: there is a general principle that doing an action that 'may' result in a melacha is fine, but something that will 'definitely' result in a melacha (psik reisha) is typically forbidden, depending on the specifics.

Comment: Is http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/57485/5275 dupe or related?

Comment: @Hugh, citation needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am extracting several answers from  [this article](http://www.communitym.com/article.asp?article_id=103107) that may be relevant:

> May one use a ponytail holder to make a ponytail in her hair on
>   Shabbat?
>
> Making a ponytail and using a ponytail holder is permitted on Shabbat,
>   as this is unlikely to cause the removal of hair (Yalkut Yosef,
>   303:15).

So, in general, you can make a ponytail. However, since you stated that it is quite likely that your hair may fall out,

> May one stroke his beard on Shabbat?
>
> Strictly speaking, it is permissible to stroke one’s beard on Shabbat,
>   **despite the possibility of hairs being detached**, because the person
>   neither intends to remove hair nor has any interest in doing so, and
>   this outcome is not guaranteed to occur.  Nevertheless, Hacham Ovadia
>   Yosef (in Yalkut Yosef) rules that it is preferable to avoid stroking
>   one’s beard on Shabbat.

So, it is really based mainly on the intent, and since you have no intent to remove your hair, there is a leniency.

Comment: RE: Your last line "mainly on the intent". I don't know exactly how to measure what's considered 'mainly' vs. 'partly', but, even in your answer, it says that there is a second qualification that affects permissibility: guaranteed outcome. The action needs to be unintended, as well as not guaranteed, for it to be permissible. One without the other doesn't work.

Comment: @Salmononius2 Thanks. I never knew about that nuance. Is there some source that explains this rule in a bit more detail?

Comment: A lot of ink has been spilled on that topic. It's known as Psik Reisha (literally: Remove the Head. A shortening of the rhetorical question "Psik Reisha Velo Yamus?" "Can you remove the head [of a chicken] and it won't die?"). It's one of the biggies of Hilchos Shabbos, so it's discussed in several places. As with just about anything Shabbos related, a good place to start looking would be Rabbi Ribiat's 4 volume 39 Melochos book.

Comment: @Salmononius2 Thanks. I have that series home. Not easy reading b/c of the vast array of topics, but he does explain things quite well. (Not that I condone them, but, I somewhat understand why many Jews choose to violate Shabbat.)