# Different editions of שמירת שבת כהלכתה – how do they compare?

Tags: shabbat, history, jewish-books

[Shokhet](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/5323/shokhet), a user of this website, mentions in his bio that when he cites שמירת שבת כהלכתה (hereinafter שש”ך) that he uses the second edition. What (other than the cover) are the major differences between editions of שש”ך?

Comment: IIRC he did that because once he cited it and I looked it up in my first edition copy and couldn't find the reference.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shemirat_Shabbat_Kehilchatah#Controversy (though I wouldn't trust it too much on the details)

Comment: You might add to this question an indication of when each edition was published, or a request for such indication in the answers. (See comments at http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/37214 .)

Comment: @DoubleAA, IIRC, there's now a third edition, which was published after R' Neuwirth זצ”ל died.

Comment: @msh210, re your cited answer, I've never seen a חלק ב to any edition of שש”ך I've come across, despite the fact that they all have an א on the spine.

Comment: @msh210, after writing this, I found (and purchased) a copy of the blue edition of חלק ב

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, the first edition allowed using the water from the *Dood Shemesh* on Shabbat.

This turned out to be very controversial, so in the introduction to the 2nd edition R' Neuwirth זצ”ל just mentions that he didn't bother republishing everything.

Seems he wanted the Sefer to be usable by everybody and saw no reason to prove his point or pick a fight.

I have never seen the first edition - seems impossible to find.

(The 2nd volume came out years later and mainly discusses Kiddush and Havdala.)

(The *recent* "fat" edition was updated with *modern technology* issues and facts of life - and references the classic second edition chapter-n-verse in the margin so that students could use both versions in class.)

Comment: Do you know which edition the dark burgundy binding is? I know that my father has the blue binding, which is the same edition as my copy of cheilek ב

Comment: @noach the original edition won't have an Alef or Bet on it, since it was a one volume work. My copies are very dark, perhaps black though that may have developed over time, and covered in lots of rebinding tape. I once found three copies at a used sefarim sale and bought them all. Such a rare find!

Comment: @noach bought a fourth today at another used sefarim place. Only $5! And in good condition too

Comment: @DoubleAA are you in Pesach Sommers’s seforim exchange group on Facebook?

Comment: @noac no and I've never heard of it (not much of a Facebook user)

Comment: @DoubleAA https://m.facebook.com/groups/1756610537926472?ref=bookmarks